# Finding Connection Pairs

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose we have a table in mySQL database where fname has a connection to another fname(BB_Connection_name), we would like have a query to find the pair(s) of friends who find connection among themselves.

E.g
Sidharth and Asim both have each others BBid and BB_Connection_ID

[image]

I have looked for similar case of father, son and grandson question but in that not each father has a son and thus inner joining them makes things easier for solving. I tried using that but didn't work.

Here i need to check BB_Connection_ID for every fname(A) and then corresponding fname has A's BBid as his BB_Connection_ID or not.

The pairs which would be chosen, should be like Sidharth<->Asim
We need to find the pairs who have their connection ID to each other.

==========================================================================

```
Code for recreation of the table:
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
create table world.bigbb(
BBid int not null auto_increment,
fname varchar(20) NOT NULL,
lname varchar(30),
BBdays int not null,
No_of_Nom int,
BB_rank int not null,
BB_Task varchar(10),
BB_Connection_ID int,
BB_Connection_name varchar(10),
primary key (BBid)
);


insert into world.bigbb (fname, lname, BBdays, No_of_Nom, BB_rank, BB_Task, BB_Connection_ID, BB_Connection_name)
values 
('Sidharth', 'Shukla', 40, 4, 2, 'Kitchen', 11, 'Asim'),
('Arhaan', 'Khan', 7, 1, 9, 'Kitchen', 16, 'Rashmi'),
('Vikas', 'Bhau', 7, 1, 8, 'Bedroom', 11, 'Asim'),
('Khesari', 'Bihari', 7, 1, 12, 'Kitchen', 9, 'Paras'),
('Tehseem', 'Poonawala', 7, 1, 11, 'Washroom', 12, 'Khesari'),
('Shehnaaz', 'Gill', 40, 4, 4, 'Washroom', 9, 'Paras'),
('Himanshi', 'Khurana', 7, 0, 7, 'Bedroom', 8, 'Shefali'),
('Shefali', 'Zariwala', 7, 1, 10, 'Bedroom', 1, 'Sidharth'),
('Paras', 'Chabra', 40, 3, 1, 'Bathroom', 10, 'Mahira'),
('Mahira', 'Sharma', 40, 4, 5, 'Kitchen', 9, 'Paras'),
('Asim', 'Khan', 40, 3, 3, 'Bathroom', 1, 'Sidharth'),
('Arti', 'Singh', 40, 5, 6, 'Captain', 1, 'Sidharth'),
('Sidharth', 'Dey', 35, 6, 16, 'None', 14, 'Shefali'),
('Shefali', 'Bagga', 38, 5, 15, 'None', 13, 'Sidharth'),
('Abu', 'Fifi', 22, 5, 17, 'None', 11, 'Asim'),
('Rashmi', 'Desai', 38, 5, 13, 'None', 17, 'Debolina'),
('Debolina', 'Bhattacharjee', 38, 5, 14, 'None', 16, 'Rashmi');
```

Comment: I can't figure out what your question is.  Desired results is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to self-join the table:

```
select
    b1.fname name1,
    b2.fname name2
from bigbb b1
inner join bigbb b2
    on  b1.BB_Connection_ID = b2.BBid 
    and b2.BB_Connection_ID = b1.BBid 
    and b1.BBid < b2.BBid
```

This will give you one record for each pair, with the record having the smallest `BBid` in the first column.

This **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=36de2c09e5926c78e7cf625d576cf3a9)** with your sample data returns:

```
name1    | name2   
:------- | :-------
Sidharth | Asim    
Paras    | Mahira  
Sidharth | Shefali 
Rashmi   | Debolina
```

Comment: :-D worked for me, I took it too complicated and oversaw this possibility. Thank You!